# Secure erase doesn't work with my hard drive

Tags: sata

I have a 2TB hard drive with a MB2000GCWDA driver.  When I run secure erase on the drive from Parted Magic, I get the error "This routine can only be run on disks supporting the Security Mode feature set."  On Amazon, the MB2000GCWDA is listed as a SATA drive.  Aren't all SATA drives compatible with Secure Erase?  If not, how do I go about finding ones that are?

Comment: Is the drive encrypted with something like BitLocker? If so, you may need to disable the encryption before you can use secure erase. See here: https://dellwindowsreinstallationguide.com/use-of-parted-magic-to-securely-wipe-a-ssd-hssd-or-hdd/

Comment: @mont2223 : Which OS? Which file system?

Answer (score 1):

Normally, hard drives don't require drivers (mine doesn't) and can be erased by overwriting (random) data or physically destroying it. I think you don't want option 2, so you should go with option 1. You can do this through software and that is what that tool does. If parted magic secure erase doesn't work, try a different tool like CCleaner Drive Wiper of just create a tool (stackoverflow can help you with creating that tool) that will fill your hard drive with a repetitive text file of 2TB, deletes it and repeates that a few times. :)

Comment: @ *"or just create a tool […] hat will fill your hard drive with a repetitive text file "* : no need to create a tool which already exists: in Windows for example (OP didn't mention OS) there is [cipher](https://superuser.com/a/1373949/961501).